# Unexpected token 'export' while importing dynamically a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I am creating a script that would run over certain js files in my system (outside my project, actually they are plain js files in a React application)  and I want to evaluate the content of them and get the content of the variables to use them in my script. See the code here:

```js
import glob from 'glob';

const cwd = '/path/to/code';
const findAll = () => glob('**/*config.js', { cwd }, (err, matches) => {
// matches is an array of paths like ['dir/myfile-config.js']
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  const file = matches[0];
  // file here is the path to a JS file that contains something like export const CONFIG = {prop1: 'value1'};
  import(`${cwd}/${file}`)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

When I invoke the import() function it complains about:

```
export const CONFIG = {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

However it is importing correctly 'glob' library. I don't understand why it cannot import that file and could not find any info in the internet about it. I could find info about how to make node understand the module system but this is not the problem here as my program understands import/export sintaxis.
I am running my program with node 12.13.0 running the file like:

`node --experimental-modules ./index.js`

I also tried with node 13.14.0 (removing the --experimental-modules flag) and got the same result :(

Any help would be really appreciated.

I add also the package.json I am using:

```
{
  "name": "config-retriever",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "glob": "^7.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi T.J, thanks for the reply, I have added the package json. The file I am trying to import is outside this project and it is just a plain js file in a react application, it is not in a module or anything like that, my guess (with zero knowledge of how this works internally) is that the problem might go in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by default, Node.js determines whether something is a CJS module or an ESM module by using its closes `package.json`. You've said that these configs are outside the project, so there's no `package.json` to tell Node.js to treat them as ESM rather than CJS.

Options:

1. Add a `package.json` to the place where the configs are located that has `"type": "module"` in it. Literally just this does it:

   ```
   {
       "type": "module"
   }
   ```
2. You can force that by giving the config files the extension `.mjs`, which is always treated as an ESM module (and changing your `glob` call accordingly). For me that's not a great solution, but...
3. It also may be possible to use the [`getFormat` hook](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_getformat_code_hook) to tell Node that these config files are ESM, not CJS. However, a note on it says that it's in the process of being redesigned and that you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Solution 1 worked perfectly, thanks a lot T.J.! solution 2 is not an option as those files I want to read are production code and I don't want to mess with it. I will explore also option 3 taking into account the disclaimer you just mentioned. For now I think I will add the "type": "module" dynamically to package json and remove it after the script is done so I don't pollute the package json of the application. Thanks again for the superfast reply :) Have a great day!

Comment: @A.Llorente - Ah, I like that dynamic thing! :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run a particular function in a js file, you should use [Make-Runnable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-runnable) module.

Put this code snippet at the end of your js file.

```
require('make-runnable/custom')({
  // printOutputFrame: false
});
```